# Transfer data from Big query to Amazon S3 using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

How to send data from Big query to Amazon s3 using Airflow operators?

What are the operators that I need to use?  I am stuck in the middle of the process.

Here is my code so far

```
bq_check_date = BigQueryCheckOperator(
    task_id='bq_check_date',
    sql='''
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    `myproject.test.test_table`
    ''',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    bigquery_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID,
    dag=dag
)
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id="get_data",
    dataset_id=BQ_DATASET,
    table_id=BQ_TABLE,
    location=LOCATION,
    dag = dag,
    bigquery_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID,
)
```

What next ? Any ideas, thank you very much !

Answer (score 6):

You definitely can explore Apache 2.0 licensed [Astro SDK](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) maintained by [Astronomer](https://www.astronomer.io/) which allows rapid and clean development of {Extract, Load, Transform} workflows using Python and SQL, powered by Apache Airflow.

For your use case, you can try the [export_to_file](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/astro/sql/operators/export.html) operator.

The package supports various cloud providers. For Google Bigquery and Amazon S3, you can install it with `pip install "astro-sdk-python[amazon,google]"` or add this dependency to your `requirements.txt`
Alternatively, you could install the whole package with
`pip install "astro-sdk-python[all]"`

Once installed, your DAG snippet would be as minimum as the below:

```
from astro.constants import FileType
from astro.files import File
from astro import sql as aql
from astro.table import Table, Metadata
from airflow.models import DAG

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example_load_bigquery_to_s3",
    start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30),
)
with dag:
    aql.export_to_file(
        task_id="get_data",
        input_data=Table(
            conn_id="bigquery_conn_id", // This is your Google Bigquery connection name configured in Airflow
            name="test.test_table",
            metadata=Metadata(schema="myproject"),
        ),
        output_file=File(
            path="s3://your_s3_bucket/target_file_name.csv",
            conn_id="aws_default", // This is you AWS S3 connection name configured in Airflow
            filetype=FileType.CSV,
        ),
        if_exists="replace",
    )
```

Disclaimer: I work at Astronomer, which develops [Astro SDK](https://github.com/astronomer/astro-sdk) as an Open Source project.

Comment: TLDR; I’ve never used Astro before but I will be using it a lot more, now.

After I got my head around the concepts, configuration, dependency requirements, etc., Astro is great.  It makes your code really clean and it’s easy to write.  It was very painful for me to figure it out, though.  The documentation and errors didn’t have enough detail for me, so this turned a DAG that should have taken <10 minutes to write into a 5 day marathon.
The docs are better for Snowflake users than BigQuery users, like myself.
Anyways, thanks for the solution, @Pankaj Koti!  It’s a very nice library.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways usually:

1. You find an existing service transferring the data and use it. For example GCP has such service called BigQueryTransferService that can transfer (for example) S3 to BigQuery (but not the other way round). And you can run orchestrate it from Airflow using existing opperators or BashOperator + gcloud. I am not aware of any AWS service like that (usually you'd look for such services delivered by the "target" of your data transfer as they are more intereset in getting more data rather than sending it out). Ig you find such service, you might write your custom operator using it. Writing an Operator is [surprisingly easy](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) if there is no ready operator available or you can write a Bash  or Python Operator script doing so.
2. In case when there is no "service" you can tap into, then you need to have  so called "Transfer" operator. Which usually works in the way that it creates two Hooks (for source and target) and passes data between those - either via streaming or by extracting data from the source and storing it locally as first step and uploading it in the second step. Those two Hooks needs to be used in single Operator execution so that they can share the local data or stream. I do not think there is an existing BigQuery to S3 operator, but - again you can easily write your own custom operator that will use BigQueryHook and S3Hook and pass the data between those two.

For the second case, you can take some existing operators in Airflow as example (they are usually in "providers" and the transfers operators are usually in "transfers" package. Example here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/gcs_to_s3.py . As you look there there is a lot of documentation and some boilerplate code and handling multiple files but the gist of it is:

```
    file_bytes = hook.download(object_name=file, bucket_name=self.bucket)
    s3_hook.load_bytes(cast(bytes, file_bytes), key=dest_key, replace=self.replace, acl_policy=self.s3_acl_policy)
```

As you see - in this case the GCS file is downloade locally (to memory in this case) and uploaded to S3 using hooks.

Hooks are very important entity in Airflow - they encapsulate authentication and provide simple API to services, so writing operators when you already have hooks is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since the question was made but this may help others in the future.

In the same context as Jarek placed it, you can start from [SQLtoS3 operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/transfer/sql_to_s3.html) which is really close to what you want to achieve in order to build you own operator.

You need to change the [_get_hook method](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/sql_to_s3.html) to return a BigQueryHook just by initialising an BigQueryHook object (don't use get_connection and get_hook methods). Also in the get_pandas_df method in the execute method you may need to adjust the dialect used for your queries I had problems with default legacy needed to change it to standard.